# duplicate entries while inserting data from jtable to derby database

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I wrote code to insert values from a jtable to a derby database. the code does insert the values but in a funny way. because i have 7 columns the codes insert a single entry 7 times with the first row insert missing a single value and the second insert misses 2 values and so on... here is the code below.

```
try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
        pst = con.prepareStatement("Insert into APP.ASSESSOR" +
            "(EMPLOYEEID, NAME, SURNAME,ASSESSORNUMBER," +
            "UNITSTANDARDNUMBER, DESCRIPTION, CREDITS, NQFLEVEL)"+
            "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        TableModel tm = jTable1.getModel();
        for(int row = 0; row < tm.getRowCount(); row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < tm.getColumnCount(); col++){
                Object val = tm.getValueAt(row, col);
                pst.setObject(col+1, val);
                pst.addBatch();
            }
        }
        pst.executeBatch();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record successfully saved..!");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should move `addBatch()` to out side of inner loop.first you should set values to statement .ones you add all columns call `addBatch()`

```
for(int col = 0; col < tm.getColumnCount(); col++){
        Object val = tm.getValueAt(row, col);
        pst.setObject(col+1, val);

}
pst.addBatch();
```

Comment: @Herb21 are you still get duplicate entries ?? then you shouldn't accept the answer

Comment: i no longer get duplicate values your recommendation worked.